# how do you install PHP libraries on XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp

So I know that to install a PHP librabry usually you install it in the /lib/ folder on the webserver however I can't find a /lib/ folder on XAMPP and I'm trying to install Swiftmailer in XAMPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAMPP is the tools stack that allows you to run PHP applications on an Apache server (Perl and MySQL also). It isn't supposed to *keep* any kind of library.

I suggest you saving your libraries in your project's folder.
Or in a *global* folder that you will add to your PHP [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Comment: Could you please explain how I could go about doing that? I'm a complete PHP newbie.

Comment: Simply, create a folder called *lib/* in your project's root directory and put Swiftmailer in it.

Comment: @SamyDindane so what are all the steps to make a chosen library work? on *unix  I do apt-get install <my-program> and then it'r runnable with 'exec' for instance. How to install it in Xampp? just putting in in /lib won't work

Comment: @trainoasis Sorry, I don't use PHP anymore so I can't help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

In /php/ext you can drop php extensions, remember to add them to php.ini later in /php/php.ini with the respective configuration.
You can also use PECL.In /php/ext you can drop php extensions, remember to add them to php.ini later in /php/php.ini with the respective configuration. You can also use PECL.

Comment: He's talking about PHP libraries (such as Swiftmailer), not extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The `/lib/` folder (at the very least on the Windows version, where I work on a lot) is in the `/php/` folder and not in the main `/` folder!